# Displaying empty spaces in a string

Tags: c++, string

I am busy with a practical. I have to enter a string or a message and have to convert it to Morse code: 
'A' = .-
'B' = -...
ecs.

I can do that with no problem by using a series of if statements.

```
for(int i = 0;i < stringvalue.length();i++)
{
    if(stringvalue == 'A')
        cout << ".-";
        //there is 26 if statements

}
```

But when i enter a string, eg.

```
"Testing data"
```

Only the first part of the string is converted(test is converted) to Morse.

Why does it not convert the part after the space. If there is a space in the string it must output "/ ".

Comment: Using `cin >> ` will break at the space. Look at using `getline` instead: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: Also, instead of using 26 `if`s, maybe you could use a table (array) of Morse code values, and look up each letter in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your input routine looks like this:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
```

The input is read up to the first whitespace character. To read the whole line, you can use `std::getline`.

```
std::getline(std::cin, input);
```

Comment: Thank you that helped. I will accept your answer in 10 minutes;

Answer (score 2):

Because you're reading the string from `stdin` using `cin >> stringvalue`.  The C++ [`operator>>(istream, string)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) stops after whitespace; it reads only a single space-separated token at a time.

Instead, use [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
std::getline(std::cin, stringvalue);
```